# loop through request.form and create the variables with proper values. in ASP CLASSIC

Tags: forms, asp-classic, request, eval

I have several forms, with tons of key/values that should be different from form to form, but refers to the same "item".

i would like to make a ASP script that takes all these key/values and creates the variables with values. i mean, if i have a text field named "name_field_codenumber" with a value of "32_someName" i would like to create a variable named `name_field_codenumber` witha  value of `32_someName`, so i can test that variable print, end so on, i've done this:

```
for each x in Request.Form 
        x.name = Request.Form(x) 
next
```

which bring me a 500 error, object required

and this

```
 for each x in Request.Form 
            eval(x) = Request.Form(x) 
    next
```

which returns a type mismatch...

may someone help me, i think it should be very easy but i can't get this thing to work :D

Answer (score 1):

i Have found the solution, and it's quite simple :

```
For Each Field in Request.Form
TheString = Field & "=Request.Form(""" _
& Field & """)"
EXECUTE(TheString)
Next
```